# Circuit explanation, role of the trimpot and capacitor, as shown in a part of the circuit

Tags: pic, usb, usb-host

Here is a part of the [IOIO circuit](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki)

[image].

Wondering if someone could explain the role played by the trimpot (R2) there (why not a fixed resistor?) and the role of the capacitor (C5).

Comment: Aaarrrrgghh. Whoever drew that schematic has no respect for anyone else who might work on it.

Comment: Well, the designer was kind enough to make it an open-source hardware design, but I guess doesn't make a living (or mostly) from designing these things, so I'd be slightly less harsh, and say that it might be an oversight :-) Anyway, to a casual tinkerer like me, the part of circuit seems pretty neat (and beyond my grasp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion arises because the schematics is poorly drawn.  C5 is connected between 3.3V and Ground, while the 3.3V is also connected to pin 35 -> it is a decoupling cap.  the trim pot is connected as a variable resistor from the 5V rail and VBus, so it is acting as a Pullup resistor.  In the USB spec the various pulllup's on various pins allows for setup information to be determined by the various devices - so it looks like this meant to be adjustable for either experimentation reasons or other more subtle reasons.

As an aside, the floating end of the TRIM Pot should be connected to the wiper.

Typically the D+/D- lines have pullups to indicate speed class, but there I can't find the place in the spec where the Vusb is pulled up.

[USB  V2.0 spec here from the source](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_20_071012.zip)

You can tell this is a high speed connection because of the lack of  Pullup resistor on the D+/D- lines.  My best guess is that the resistor on the Vusb is mean as a current limiter to ensure that only self powered devices attach.  If it draws any amount of power the voltage drops and the device will reset itself.  But someone with a more intimate knowledge of the spec will ave to comment.

Comment: Thanks @rawbrawb. R2 being a trimpot, is there a pot rating that one could assume -- 10K, 100K ? Or better still, a suitably rated fixed resistor, I could replace it with ?

Comment: I'd measure the real device, since it "appears" to be non standard.

Comment: Having thought about it - if I am right then you should be able to find out what is considered a standard load from the document I linked to as well as the threshold voltages and calculate it yourself.  A resistor would be better and saver that a small trimpot

Comment: Not being very electronics literate, bit hard for me to calculate the resistor value. Anyhow, will keep the question open for a few more days in the hope that someone might explain how to compute the resistor value, else will accept this answer.